# CSS hover effecting two divs

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website that is going to have a double hover effect on an image.

First the image is going to shrink in height and secondly there is going to be a "Read More" text on the image.

The problem I'm facing is that when the mouse hovers to the "Read More" text, the image goes back to it's full height...

I've tried to add to a :hover statement to the "Read More" -text but it's not working...

Comment: also add code that you have tried

Comment: Can you post example code please?

Comment: Please share your code with us or see 

How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example[https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

See code below. Hope this helps.

```css
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.image>img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.image>div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
}

.image:hover>img {
  width: 100px;
}

.image:hover>div {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
  <div>Read more</div>
</div>
```